# Range not working across sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code in VBA. The issue with the below code is range is referring to `data` sheet and as soon as I am in some other sheet it fails.

```
monthname = Range("D5", Range("D5").End(xlToRight)).Cells.Count - 1
```

Can you please provide me a solution wherein no matter where I am in the workbook range should always pick from the `data` sheet?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
monthname = sheets("data").Range("D5", sheets("data").Range("D5").End(xlToRight)).Cells.Count - 1
```

btw a small search on this forum or google would have got you this answer.

Comment: You need to qualify the second `Range` call with the worksheet too.

Comment: The above code works like a Charm.....extremely thankful to you guys and everyone who has replied to my issue...withour you all it wouldnt have been possible

Comment: @Sanchos..99moorem answered my question

Comment: @SrijithRamachandran I think the comment was made so that you could mark it as answered

Answer (score 0):

You are better off fully qualifying your ranges.
Use

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("data")   ' or an alternative suitable for your case
Dim monthname as Long
monthname = ws.Range("D5", ws.Range("D5").End(xlToRight)).Cells.Count - 1
```

Note that the second reference to D5 is also qualified, otherwise you may find troubles.

PS: Why would you have a month name as an integer?

Comment: Dear Sanchos, many thanks for the suggestion. i have implemented your code but its not working unfortunately...when i run the code with sheet named"control" as active, it refers to sheet named "control" and not sheet "data"...

Comment: @SrijithRamachandran That is not possible using the code provided.

Comment: @Rory can you suggest me any other alternative. i have used "activate" also but it just breaks the code and go to the selected sheet and will not move further

Comment: If you use the code as posted here, it has to work. There is no way it could refer to the "control" sheet.

Answer (score 0):

use

monthname = sheets("data").Range("D5", sheets("data").Range("D5").End(xlToRight)).Cells.Count - 1
btw a small search on this forum or google would have got you this answer.